# How to save a ModelSerializer with a foreign Key in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these **serializers**

```py
class OwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name'
        ]


class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = OwnerSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'owner'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Pet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        owner_data = validated_data.pop('owner', None)
        if owner_data:
            owner = User.objects.get(**owner_data)
            validated_data['owner'] = owner
        return Pet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

This is my **ViewSet**:

```py
class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    ModelViewSet for model pets
    """
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['owner'] = {'id': request.user.id, 'name': request.user.name}
        pet_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        pet_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(pet_serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(pet_serializer.data)
        return Response(pet_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

But when storing it, all the data is saved, but in the created function the owner object does not arrive, it is shown as `'owner': OrderedDict ()}`

So when I return the saved object, I get it with the owner with the default id, although the user I get in the view is `'owner': {'id': 10, 'name': 'My name'}} ):`

My **Json Response**:

```
{
    "id": 26,
    "name": "My pet",
    "owner": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the next changes in my **Serializers**,the main changes was in the OwnerSerializer, 'cause the id was read only for default.

```py
class OwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {
                'read_only': False,
                'required': True
            }
        }


class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = OwnerSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'owner'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Pet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        owner_data = validated_data.pop('owner', None)
        if owner_data:
            owner = User.objects.get(**owner_data)
            validated_data['owner'] = owner
        return Pet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: I added some info

Answer (score 0):

.get returns one item and if it matched more, It raises an expception.

`owner = User.objects.get(**owner_data)`, remove the trailing `[0]`

*EDIT:* Since this was not your problem, I'll tell you the problem

You're overriding `create` which have the `validated_data`, You assumed that the owner is validated but it may wrong. 
Do the same logic in a method named `validate_owner(self, value)` in which `value` is the `value` you passed for `owner` in the `POST` before it gets validated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's returning normalized data of the owner object, rather than the relation.

Instead of `owner = OwnerSerializer()` try something like:
`owner = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Owner.objects.all())`

Comment: Almost!, but when I perform the GET method it returns the id instead of the owner object `"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "my pet",
            "owner": 10
        },`